# How to Reverse Static in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I work with huge datasets and was wondering if there is a code in MySQL which can perform Reverse Static(ACL function). By reverse static I mean if the dataset is :

```
ColumnA Columnb Columnc
        sam     sql
        joe     c++
batch1  jenet   java
        jerry   c
        jimmy   python
        jojo    cobol
batch2  karmin  r
```

the output will look like :

```
cola    colb    colc
batch1  sam     sql
batch1  joe     c++
batch1  jenet   java
batch2  jerry   c
batch2  jimmy   python
batch2  jojo    cobol
batch2  karmin  r
```

In ColumnA the data gets filled upwards. We get CSV files as well as Excel files in this format and a manual intervention will take days to fill those in. So is there a code which can be run to fill out those data using MySQL. Thanks.

P.S: I can add an incremental ID if that helps

Comment: No, there is no way to do this from MySQL, because rows in SQL databases have no explicit ordering.  You would need to at least have some column which groups together records belonging to the same `cola` group.

Comment: ... or an incrementing id

Comment: If i add an incrementing ID will that help? That I can do , I can place a column with the an incrementing ID!

Comment: do let me know if that will work ?